# Added Variables Not Filling Out When Merging Files

Tags: spss

I have two data sets that I want to Merge on the variable Survey ID.

The first data set can have one survey ID listed more than once. 
The second data set will only have unique IDs.

I chose **Data-->Merge Files-->Add Variables-->Join on Survey ID**.

But, I can see in my exported data that whenever a survey ID repeated in the first data set, it didnt merge properly with the second data set.

See below for what happened:

[image]

So Country and Segment came from the second data set. But you can see that on the second instance of ID 1013304, it's not filling in. I want that blank row to also say Country: Japan, Segment: C.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be your problem is not sorting both files in advance. In any case this should work for you:

```
*open the file with unique data.
sort cases by Survey_ID.
dataset name unique_data.

*open second file.
sort cases by Survey_ID.
dataset name full_data.
match file /file=* /table=unique_data/by Survey_ID.
exe.
```

Comment: This does solve that issue...but it also creates another issue in comparison. When I originally joined the files, it took every row from both files. In your example, it only took the rows from the full_data data set...but then there are rows in the unique_data that aren't being included. So in this case my N counts are all off. Is there a way to almost combine these two methods?

Comment: Perhaps I need to be more clear on the issue: The unique_data file is actually all of the survey responses. So everyone can only answer once and when I look at N counts, I'm interested in this population. The full_data is a file of optional questions the respondents can answer, and they can answer each one more than once (hence why their SurveyID can show up multiple times). So essentially what I want is the combination of our two methods so that the final N count comes from the unique_data (which is what I got the 1st time) but that its completely filled in (which is what you achieved above)

Comment: For this you should change the match command like this: `match file /file=* /file=unique_data/by Survey_ID.` (use `file` again instead of `table`).

Comment: This seems to bring me back to the first issue where I now have blank rows again that arent being populated by the second file (see screenshot above...it's the exact same issue on the exact same Survey IDs)

Comment: hmmm that's right, you must have gotten an error message too? in any case this is a new problem, you should post it separately. Matching two files, both files contributing cases, one of the files has duplicate key values.